# Hypernym for 'parallel' and 'antiparallel'

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

What is a word that includes both *parallel* and *antiparallel* ?

This bothers me all the time when I do my math or physics homework.

Comment: Strictly speaking, *parallel* is the hypernym -- *antiparallel* is, a type of parallel. Incidentally, the "ortho-" parallel is the other type (hyponym).

Comment: @Kris Ooooh, ok, I was wondering if that was the case. That answers my question. Why do people always answer questions in comments...

Answer (score 1):

Those are words used to describe the orientation of lines relative to other lines. I would use "relative orientation".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that *[direction](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&site=&source=hp&q=define%20direction&oq=define%20direction&gs_l=hp.3..35i39j0l9.395.2619.0.2717.17.13.0.0.0.0.315.1530.0j5j2j1.8.0.ecynfh...0...1.1.56.hp..10.7.1353.0.t8g17Rsdlas)* would be a good hypernym.  Parallel is a way of describing  a direction or orientation of an object:

> **Parallel** 
>   1. a :  extending in the same direction, everywhere equidistant, and not meeting

[Source (Merriam-Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parallel)

Antiparallel is similar

> **Antiparallel**:  parallel but oppositely directed or oriented

[Source (Merriam-Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antiparallel)

Comment: That is not quite how you find a common parent. Direction is but one part of the story.

Answer (score 0):

The word you need is *collinear*. Collinear vectors could have same or opposite directions. https://math.tutorvista.com/calculus/collinear-vectors.html

Comment: Could you provide an example, please?

Comment: Never mind. You are correct, under standard representation and definiots, parallel" and "collinear" are synonymous terms for vectors.